# how to close division inside division

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

might be I can't describe my problem in one line title .. the description is as follows..

i made  a prompt using division .. the html on the page is ..

```html
<button id="prompt_open" name="prompt_open">open</button>
<div id="prompt" style="display:none"></div>
```

now I generate the properties of and html inside the prompt through the javascript(jquery) code ..

```javascript
$("#post_video").click(function () {
        var the_prompt = $("#Stuffprompt_main");
        the_prompt.css('display', 'block');
        var prompt_html = "";
        the_prompt.css('top', '95px');
        the_prompt.css('position', 'absolute');
        the_prompt.css('left', '300px');
        the_prompt.css('width', '610px');
        the_prompt.css('border', 'thin');
        the_prompt.css('background-color', '#FFF');
        the_prompt.css('height', 'auto');
        the_prompt.css('z-index', '9999');
        the_prompt.attr('id', 'post_prompt');
        the_prompt.attr('name', 'post_prompt');

        var shut_box = "<a id=\"close_prompt_vdo\" name=\"close_prompt_vdo\" class=\"shut\"></a>";

        var header = '<div class="header_prompt"><span id="pr" class="prompt_title">Post video of your stuff</span></div>';
        var middler = "<form action=\"user_posting/post_video.php\" name=\"posting_photos\" id=\"posting_photos\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">" +
            "<div class=\"object_container\">" +
            "<textarea name=\"title_postvideo\" id=\"title_postvideo\" class=\"descriptor\" maxlength=\"100\" placeholder=\"Tilte\" style=\"height:30px;\" ></textarea>" +
            "<textarea name=\"text_postvideo\" id=\"text_postvideo\" class=\"descriptor\" maxlength=\"200\" placeholder=\"Add some description\" ></textarea>" +
            "<div class=\"file_Container\">" +
            "<div class=\"text_box_container\">" +
            "<textarea name=\"YTB_link\" id=\"YTB_link\"  class=\"descriptor\" style=\"float:left;width:75%; border:thin; border-color: #333;\"  maxlength=\"200\" placeholder=\"Add link of your video on You tube\"></textarea>" + "<div style=\"float:left; width:120px; height:80px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url(images/tube_logo.jpg);\"></div></div>" + "<div class=\"gap\"></div>" + "<div class=\"text_box_container\">" + "<textarea name=\"VMO_link\" id=\"VMO_link\" class=\"descriptor\" style=\"float:left;width:75%; border:thin; border-color: #333;\"  maxlength=\"200\" placeholder=\"Add link of your video on Vimeo\"></textarea>" + "<div style=\"float:left; width:135px; height:80px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url(images/vm_logo.jpg);\"></div></div></div><center>" + "<button id=\"post_video_submit\" class=\"base_buttons\" style=\"margin-top:10px;\"></button>" + "</center></div></form>" + "<div class=\"gap\"></div>";


        var HTML = shut_box + header + middler;
        the_prompt.html(HTML);
        $("#close_prompt_vdo").click(function () {

            the_prompt.css('display', 'none');

        });
```

for the first time the code works i.e the "button prompt_open" opens the prompt and the button "close me"  closes the prompt .. but on second time when i click button "open prompt" nothing happens i.e the prompt doesn't displays ..

What to do??

Comment: first time Ive seen someone calling `<div>` as a division :)

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/4j32E/) (as soon as I add the missing `});` in the end). What browser are you using, is this your whole script?

Comment: @passionateCoder Makes sense, since "div" could be interpreted as an abbreviation for "division".  :)

Comment: Tell me, [whats not wroking](http://jsfiddle.net/wkFxr/) ?

Comment: As @worksforme said: http://jsfiddle.net/r8DZX/

Comment: @passionateCoder for the second time the prompt division(:P) named "prompt" is not displaying

Comment: @Mukurpuri: Can you make a demo that shows this issue? We cannot reproduce it with the little code you gave us.

Comment: @passionateCoder *The div element, short for division, is the block level generic container.* - http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements

Comment: @passionateCoder [your div for division](http://full-form.in/DIV.html) .. may be possible geeks are more naturalistic

Comment: @Mukurpuri show us some more code.. i dont think this is causing the problem

Comment: is the prompt open button being replaced at all on the page? If it is you will need to rebind the click even or change it to `on` or some other form of delegation...

Comment: @Mukurpuri i think u need to learn the importance of chaining in jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> the_prompt.attr('id', 'post_prompt');
> ```

is the evil line. Why are you doing that? It makes it impossible to select the `var the_prompt` as `$("#Stuffprompt_main")` the second time.

Some possibilities to fix the issue:

- remove that line (maybe you actually don't need it)
- move the `var the_prompt = $("#Stuffprompt_main");` assignment outside the `click` handler so that it will not get executed every time (and still point to the element when the id was changed)
- reset the `id` attribute from the close-click-handler

Comment: thank you i was buzzed for past 3 hours .. for this short evil line .. but why its the evil .. why it creates the problem

Comment: Didn't I explain that? When `$("#Stuffprompt_main")` in the click handler is executed the second time, it will not find the element any more - it has a different `id` now. Setting innerHTML or css on the empty wrapper will have no effect.